# regex preserve whitespace in replace

Tags: regex, powershell, whitespace

Using REGEX (in PowerShell) I would like to find a pattern in a text file that is over two lines and replace it with new text and preserve the whitespace.  Example text:

```
    ObjectType=Page
    ObjectID=70000
```

My match string is

```
RunObjectType=Page;\s+RunObjectID=70000
```

The result I want is

```
   ObjectType=Page
   ObjectID=88888
```

The problem is my replacement string

```
RunObjectType=Page;`n+RunObjectID=88888
```

returns

```
       ObjectType=Page
ObjectID=88888
```

And I need it to keep the original spacing.  To complicate matters the amount of spacing may change.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leverage a capturing group and a backreference to that group in the replacement pattern:

```
$s -replace 'RunObjectType=Page;(\s+)RunObjectID=70000', 'RunObjectType=Page;$1RunObjectID=88888'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vffhv7/1)

With the `(\s+)`, you *capture* all the whitespaces into the Group 1 buffer and then, using `$1` backreference, the value is inserted into the result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be simple but I could not see it.